# Read a external json file in Neutralino app

Tags: json, neutralinojs

How can I read a external json file to populate my HTML?
I read the docs and see "filesystem.readFile(string filename, function success(data), function error)" but I don't know how can I set to read the file or what is the right folder to put the file.

Comment: I managed, changing json to js. I think neutralino don't parse json for now.

Answer (score 1):

This code from the docs prints the data from the json file. Consider parsing the returned json. **NOTE : the function should always be an "async" function or it won't work.**

```js
async function readMyjsonFile(){
    let response = await Neutralino.filesystem.readFile({
        fileName: './myFile.json'
    });
    console.log(`Content: ${response.data}`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery you can use `jQuery.getJSON()` (https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/).

```
jQuery.getJSON('relativePath/myFile.json',function(data){
  //Do something with your json data
}
```

or

```
jQuery.getJSON('file:///absolutePath/myFile.json',function(data){
  //Do something with your json data
}
```